# OpenCV header error (YAML)

Tags: opencv, yaml

Ok so I feel that I have finally successfully used the OpenCV libraries in my app, except for one thing...

My .yml files get generated correctly except the '%YAML:1.0' header at the top turns out like this '01%YAML:1.0'. The '01' infront of the header is causing this error (I think):

```
OpenCV Error: Parsing error (/var/mobile/Applications/53C6CBA3-15B7-436A-892B-2ECFA75B72CD/Library/DownloadedDescriptors/descriptors.yml(1): Valid XML should start with '<?xml ...?>') in icvXMLParse, file /Users/Dash/Documents/SmartServices/AirLink/ProjectGhost/FairfaxNewsDemo/opencv-2.3.1/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp, line 2163
```

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Ok after looking into it a bit further I dont think it's the headers problem. My file always gets generated with '01' at the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm...this is embarrassing. But it turns out that I had a 'print' statement lingering in the php file that helps generate my .yaml file, causing 0 and 1 to be added to the beginning of the document.

This meant that my file didn't start with '%YAML:1.0' as expected but '01%YAML:1.0'